# Restore database from backup drupal 8

Tags: backup, restore, drupal-8

I accidentally deleted my drupal 8 files. But my database is not damaged right now. Is there anyway I can bring my site back to live.

**What I did:** I have my site old backup [only files]. Copied those backup to root folder replaced database credentials in settings.php. But no luck.

Any other way to bring back my site live from database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have drush you try with

```
drush sql-cli < my_directory/my_drupal8_dump.sql
```

So, in you backup files just run this command, not need to update settings.php

Comment: it's shared hosting. I couldn't install drush.